# how to copy a list of specific files using batch?

Tags: batch-file

Consider i am having a file input.txt which contains file list 
**input.txt**  
ExampleTestthreeBean.class 
ExampleTestoneBean.class

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (input.txt) do ( 
      dir /s /b D:\com\example_4.1\%%a>>Dirfilelisttemp.txt 
    )

**kind of folder structure**  
..\pgmtestone\ExampleTestoneBean.class
..\pgmtestone\ExampleTestoneBean$1Sort.class
..\pgmtestone\ExampleTestoneBean$2.class
..\pgmtestone\ExampleTestoneBean$3.class
..\pgmtesttwo\ExampleTesttwoBean.class
..\pgmtesttwo\ExampleTesttwoBean$1.class
..\pgmtesttwo\ExampleTesttwoBean$2.class
..\pgmtesttwo\ExampleTestthreeBean.class
..\pgmtesttwo\ExampleTestthreeBean$1Math.class
..\pgmtesttwo\ExampleTestthreeBean$2Scroll.class
..\pgmtesttwo\ExampleTestthreeBean$2Scroll.class

**Note: Desired output:**  
..\pgmtestone\ExampleTestoneBean.class
..\pgmtestone\ExampleTestoneBean$1Sort.class
..\pgmtestone\ExampleTestoneBean$2.class
..\pgmtestone\ExampleTestoneBean$3.class
..\pgmtesttwo\ExampleTestthreeBean.class
..\pgmtesttwo\ExampleTestthreeBean$1Math.class
..\pgmtesttwo\ExampleTestthreeBean$2Scroll.class
..\pgmtesttwo\ExampleTestthreeBean$2Scroll.class

**Actual output:**
**Dirfilelisttemp.txt** 
..\pgmtesttwo\ExampleTestthreeBean.class
..\pgmtestone\ExampleTestoneBean.class

After executing this, i am getting "actual output". But i couldn't get the desired output. is there any solution for getting desired output?

Answer (score 0):

if you tell him to show `ExampleTestoneBean.class`, he will show exactly that.
What you want is `ExampleTestoneBean*.class`. To achieve this, use this:

```
dir /s /b /a-d "D:\com\example_4.1\%%~na*%%~xa" >> "Dirfilelisttemp.txt"
```

`%%~na` : show name of `a` only

`%%~xa` : show extension of `a` only.

(described in `for /?`)

Comment: Try it now with quotes added to support long file/pathname elements.

Comment: There was an extra `.` period in the line.  Try it again.